# What can I do for this image to not grow bigger in the section?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap 4.6 and WordPress with ACF Plugin and I need help with something here. I need that the row of a section adjust its height with the col that has the text and stuff, but the image grows bigger and makes the row grow bigger too, and that's causing a big space at the bottom. I need the adjustment to be automatic because the content and image of the section will be dynamic. It can change and because of that I can't simply set a max height.

[Image 1: Top of the section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBC2R.png)

[Image 2: Bottom of the section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpwwV.png)

[Image 3: Bottom of the section showing the extra space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzCIJ.png)

[Image used in the section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQbXK.png)

```
    <section id="about">
        <div class="about-section position-relative overflow-hidden" style="background: linear-gradient(180deg, #00AEA0 0%, rgba(0, 131, 120, 0.5) 118.6%);">
            <img class="position-absolute bottom-0 right-0" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/assets/img/about-us-background.png" style="max-width: 50%;">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 px-0">
                    <?php if (get_field('about_image')) : ?>
                        <img class="w-100 h-100 object-cover d-none d-lg-block" src="<?php the_field('about_image');; ?>">
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>

                <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 offset-lg-1">
                    <div class="px-4 px-lg-0 py-5 py-md-6">
                        <h1 class="title text-lg-left"><?php the_field('about_title'); ?></h1>

                        <div class="text-md-justify mt-4">
                            <?php the_field('about_text'); ?>
                        </div>

                        <a href="<?php the_field('about_button_link'); ?>" class="btn-custom btn-blue-1 mt-3 px-4 px-md-5"><?php the_field('about_button_text'); ?></a>

                        <div class="row gap-8 gap-lg-4 mt-5">

                            <?php if (have_rows('benefits')) : ?>
                                <?php while (have_rows('benefits')) : the_row(); ?>

                                    <div class="col-12 col-sm">
                                        <div class="d-flex flex-column gap-4">
                                            <div class="hover-flip">
                                                <div class="benefit-icon">
                                                    <?php if (get_sub_field('image')) : ?>
                                                        <img src="<?php the_sub_field('image'); ?>">
                                                    <?php endif ?>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <span class="font-weight-bold text-lg"><?php the_sub_field('name'); ?></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                <?php endwhile; ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

I've tried using this CSS properties: "`width: 100%; height: 100%; object-fit: cover;`" on the image and it's not working the way I want.

Comment: It's hard to post an accurate answer without seeing the css at least for its div container.
Have you tried applying an object-fit property to the div? https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_object-fit.asp

Comment: @AtomicUs5000 There are no custom CSS in that code besides the .object-cover class that applies object-fit: cover. The other classes like benefit-icon, hover-flip, btn-custom and so are simply clases for other element and they're not messing with the layout. There is this .about-section class too, but it hasn't any CSS rules at the moment. Where do you want me to apply object-fit?

Comment: I looked at it for a little bit. It's difficult to test without the images because div with class "row" is a flex and the appearance when you shrink and expand the view is highly dependent on the image dimensions. In the img tag, I changed w-100 to mw-100 and then added style="object-fit:cover" after the classes and it seemed to behave better, especially when the about text is huge.

Comment: Add height constraint such as `mx-height:300px` etc..

Comment: @AtomicUs5000 I tried what you said and didn't work... But I found a solution using position relative on the container with width and height to 100%. The image has absolute positioning, display block and, width and height to 100%. I'll post the solution as a question. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @MohammedShahed That limit the height doesn't work in this case because the content of the section is dynamic, so if the content is bigger than the actual shown in the image it'll overflow of the section. But I found a solution already. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using positioning in the container and image.

```
    <section id="about">
        <div class="position-relative overflow-hidden" style="background: linear-gradient(180deg, #00AEA0 0%, rgba(0, 131, 120, 0.5) 118.6%);">
            <img class="position-absolute bottom-0 right-0" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/assets/img/about-us-background.png" style="max-width: 50%;">

            <div class="row no-gutters">
                <div class="col-12 col-lg-4">
                    <div class="h-100-img-container">
                        <?php if (get_field('about_image')) : ?>
                            <img class="w-100 h-100 object-cover d-none d-lg-block" src="<?php the_field('about_image'); ?>">
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 offset-lg-1">
                    <div class="px-4 px-lg-0 py-5 py-md-6">
                        <h1 class="title text-lg-left"><?php the_field('about_title'); ?></h1>

                        <div class="text-md-justify mt-4">
                            <?php the_field('about_text'); ?>
                        </div>

                        <a href="<?php the_field('about_button_link'); ?>" class="btn-custom btn-blue-1 mt-3 px-4 px-md-5"><?php the_field('about_button_text'); ?></a>

                        <div class="row gap-8 gap-lg-4 mt-5">

                            <?php if (have_rows('benefits')) : ?>
                                <?php while (have_rows('benefits')) : the_row(); ?>

                                    <div class="col-12 col-sm">
                                        <div class="d-flex flex-column gap-4">
                                            <div class="hover-flip">
                                                <div class="benefit-icon">
                                                    <?php if (get_sub_field('image')) : ?>
                                                        <img src="<?php the_sub_field('image'); ?>">
                                                    <?php endif ?>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <span class="font-weight-bold text-lg"><?php the_sub_field('name'); ?></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                <?php endwhile; ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

The CSS:

```css
    .h-100-img-container {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .h-100-img-container img {
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;
        object-position: top;
    }
```